# Stacked Launcher Item Double Click Behaviour on Alt-tab

Tags: compiz, launcher, window-manager, application-switcher

Let's say that you have multiple firefox windows open. What you see happen is an additional arrow points to it's icon in the launcher. However, if you double click the icon, it displays all of the windows in a spread out fashion, similar to the behaviour from pushing Super + W, but only for that program group.

Is it possible to make this window spreading behaviour occur with alt-tab?

PS: No idea what tags I should use, or if the language (jargon) in the title or question is appropriate.

Comment: Just so you know, you can view the hotkey izx provided below and other useful shortcuts by holding down your Super (Windows) key.

Comment: I'm aware of that. But I'm looking for how to enact a specific behaviour. It's not something in that list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The shortcut to spread multiple windows that is **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>** (that's the same key as the <kbd>~</kbd>, on the top left)
- You can use it directly with the current program, or use it with *Alt+Tab* after your chosen program is highlighted.
- Firefox example:

  [image]

Comment: +1 I like this answer, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. If you double click the firefox icon on the launcher when the you have more than one page open, that's what I'd like to see happen, automatically, when I get to a group of windows via alt+tab.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen: that *does* automatically happen with alt+tab if you release tab but keep alt pressed on icons with multiple windows open...you can then use arrow keys+enter or alt+` to select whichever window you'd like to open...

Comment: Actually, no it doesn't. The behaviour that I'm looking for is akin to what happens when you press Super + W (the spread) but only for that particular stack. I'm going to update my question to make it clearer

Comment: I guess this is the closest thing to what I'm looking for.